# how to find "Number of times tagged in posts" on Facebook using FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get "Number of times a fb user tagged in posts". I have made coding to fetch basic coding and my coding is:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  FB.login();
} else {
  FB.login();
}  });
```

Code to get basic info is:

```
function testAPI() {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    pInfo = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
    name = "<strong>Your Name:</strong> "+response.name;
    fName = "<br><strong>First Name:</strong> "+response.first_name;
    lName = "<br><strong>Last Name:</strong> "+response.last_name;
    pLink = "<br><strong>Profile Link:</strong> <a href='"+response.link+"' target='_blank'>"+response.link+"</a>";
    gender = "<br><strong>Gender:</strong> "+response.gender;
    verified = "<br><strong>Verified:</strong> "+response.verified;
    pInfo .innerHTML += name+fName+lName+pLink+gender+verified;
});
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    friendCount = "<br><strong>Friends Count:</strong> "+response.data.length;
    pInfo = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
    pInfo .innerHTML += friendCount;
});  }
```

**Like that I need to show:**

Number of times tagged in posts on Facebook: (Some Value)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get "Number of times a fb user tagged in posts".

There is no easy way to do this – not even a *realistic* way.

Also the FQL `stream` table contains a field with the tagged ids, this field is not indexable. And even if you where able to query all relevant posts, you can only go so far back in time with FQL, after a while you will not get any data any more – so an overall count of how many times a user was tagged is not possible this way.

There is also the `stream_tag` table – but that gave no results at all for me when I tried with `target_id=me()`.

---

The API `user` object has connections like `photos`, `videos` and `tagged` – but from my tests in Graph API Explorer those return also posts that I was not specifically tagged in, but f.e. also posts that friends made on my wall.

Comment: Thanks for your time @CBRoe.
Is this possible to get record of last three months?
That's sufficient for me.

Comment: You can try with the tables/connections I mentioned. As for “looking back into the past”, consult the docs on how pagination works.

Comment: I've a question on FQL. Can I write FQL in a html file? Cos, I'm not supposed to use any back-end script. I'm solely allowed to write javascript alone.

Comment: You can use FQL with `FB.api` as well, `FB.api('/fql?q=SELECT…')`